# Returning a reference of data that a raw pointer point to

Tags: rust

Here's my code:

```rust
use std::ptr::NonNull;
struct S {
    i: i32
}

impl Clone for S {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        S {
            i: self.i
        }
    }
}

struct F {
    v: Vec<NonNull<S>>
}

impl F {
    pub fn func<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a mut S {
        let s = &mut unsafe {
            *self.v[0].as_ptr()
        };
        s
    }
}


fn main() {
    let f = F {
        v: vec![NonNull::new_unchecked(Box::into_raw(Box::new(S{i: 32}.clone()))); 5]
    };
    f.func();
}
```

When I compile it, the compiler reminds me that **"returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"**.

Here's my question: When I dereferenced a raw pointer, the data that it points to shouldn't be owned by the struct `self`? How come it become owned by the current function. And also the compiler reminds me that **"move occurs"** when I dereferenced the raw pointer. But I do not implement the `Copy` trait for the struct S, so it failed.

Could someone explain this to me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, your `func` very dangerous since calling it twice will create two mutable references pointing at the same data, which violates Rust's safetly rules.

Answer (score 2):

Without reading too much into the context of what you are trying to do, it is really easy to fix this issue. The error comes from the fact that the `unsafe {}` splits the operation into two parts. Whenever you want to turn a raw pointer into a reference don't split up the `&mut *x`.

```rust
// Take a new mutable reference to whatever is returned by the unsafe {} block
let s = &mut unsafe {
    // Copy whatever is stored at the raw pointer to a new owned value
    *self.v[0].as_ptr()
};

let s = unsafe {
    // Create a new mutable reference to a raw pointer
    &mut *self.v[0].as_ptr()
};
```

After that you just need to mark the `NonNull::new_unchecked` as unsafe and you are good to go.

[rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e56de14cd70e4b8d538a41d945629ca)